# function repeat (simple)

Tags: jquery

I was trying to repeat the entire function in a loop but nothing works. I tried Loop () callback, set interval(). Can someone point me to the right direction?

What would be the best method to repeat the entire animation? Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slide1").fadeIn(500, function() {
        $("#slide2").fadeIn(500, function() {
            $("#slide3").fadeIn(500, function() {
                $("#slide4").fadeIn(500, function() {
                    $("#slide5").fadeIn(500, function() {

                        $("#slide1").fadeOut(500, function() {

                            $("#slide6").fadeIn(500, function() {
                                $("#slide7").fadeIn(500, function() {
                                    $("#slide8").fadeIn(500, function() {
                                        $("#slide9").fadeIn(500, function() {});
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What should get repeated here? I am just seeing a sequence of `fadeIn` -> http://jsfiddle.net/RuX5d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @Phillip So what ever you have in the question works now.. you just want the code to be improvised.. Is that correct? – Vega
>
> Hi Vega. Yes the code works nicely but would like the `$("#slide1").fadeOut(500, function() {` to occur. thanks – Phillip

Converted the code you have like below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RuX5d/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1, dir = 1, curFx = 'fadeIn';
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (i == 6 && $('#slide1').is(':visible')) {
            $('#slide1').fadeOut(500);             
            return;
        }

        $('#slide'+ i)[curFx](500);

        i = i + 1*dir;

        if (i == 10 || i == -1) {
            dir = (dir == 1)?-1:1;
            curFx = (curFx == 'fadeIn')?'fadeOut':'fadeIn';
        }        
    }, 500);
});
```

---

I am not very sure about what you want.. but I believe you want to `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` content repeatedly.

If so, try my demo and code below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/RuX5d/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var curSlide = 0, dir = 1;
    var curFx = 'fadeIn';
    setInterval(function () {
        curSlide += 1 * dir;
        $('#slide' + curSlide)[curFx](500);
        if (curSlide == 11 || curSlide == 0) {
            curFx = (curFx == 'fadeIn')?'fadeOut': 'fadeIn';
            dir = (dir == 1)?-1: 1;
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: + 1 only answer that actually does what the OP wants.

Comment: @f0x This is pretty verbose, actually, and there are other answers here that accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Asad after your edit; verbose or not it was the only answer that did what was asked.

Comment: @f0x Mine wasn't the one I was talking about, although mine also works *now*

Comment: There is a fadeOut needs to occur for the div "#side1" in the middle of the sequence.

Comment: @Phillip So what ever you have in the question works now.. you just want the code to be improvised.. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Vega. Yes the code works nicely but would like the $("#slide1").fadeOut(500, function() { to occur. thanks

Comment: wow these are some wicked code. I noticed the it skips the "#slide6" $("#slide6").fadeIn(500, function() {. It does not seem to animate or show this layer during the process. any ideas?

Comment: Also the revised version does not continuously repeats the process.

Comment: Hi Vega thanks for the fix. The revised version seem to include the #slide6. However, it it possible to make it repeat like the first code? The second only goes to the #slide9 and then stops.

Comment: Hi Vega, your code is very impressive. Thanks for sharing your great talent. This one here seem to do the trick - http://jsfiddle.net/RuX5d/5/

Comment: Hi Vega, I am coming back to ask if you could help modify the code you provided in the past. http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/RuX5d/42/

When looping, how can we shorten the Pause on Slide 1. I'd like the pause to be the same duration as the rest. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hello Vega, I am trying to reduce the delay on the restart of the sequence. Your help would be greatly appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/philoman/RuX5d/42/

Comment: Hello Vega. I am grateful for your help. How can I get in touch with you?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout`. IDK how exactly do you want to do this... but could be something like this:

```
var i = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    var slide = '#slide' + i++;
    $(slide).fadeIn();}, 500); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should handle what you are looking for

```
function fadeFn() {
    if (curNum < 10) {
        if (direction === 'Out') {
            direction = 'In';
            curNum++;
        }
        else {
            direction = 'Out';
        }
        $("#slide" + curNum)['fade' + direction](500, fadeFn);
    }
}

var curNum = 0;
var direction = 'Out';
$(document).ready(function() {
    fadeFn();
});
```

Comment: This does not see to repeat the entire process.

Comment: I didn't get that you wanted a `fadeOut` between the `fadeIn`s from the question, should work now.

Comment: zshooter, the reason for the Slide 1 fade out is because the slide 1 is a large image and the rest of the slides are smaller tiles fading in front of the larger slide 1.

Answer (score 0):

A function like this should accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
function fadeInRepeat(start, max){
    if(start++ < max){
        $("#slide" + start).fadeIn(500, function() {
            fadeInRepeat(start, max);
        }
    }
}
```

Just call `fadeInRepeat(1,10)` to replace your original code.

Answer (score 0):

You could recurse. Here's a short version:

```
function slider(count, asc) {
    var count = count || 1;
    if (!typeof(asc) == "boolean"||count == 10||count == 1) asc = !asc;
    $("#slide"+count)[asc?"fadeIn":"fadeOut"](500, (function() {
        return function() {
            slider(asc ? ++count : --count, asc);
        };
    })());
}
slider();
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/K8pbS/1/